# Is there an AWS Sandbox or Testing environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm using the AWS API for Route53 & S3 and I would like to test out some things (like Hosted Zones) that are not free, within some sort of Sandbox, so that I won't need to actually pay for them.

Lots of major services give out some sort of a Sandbox or Testing environment (like Stripe), so that you could test the things that should cost money, without actually paying for it.

Does Amazon have something like that (specifically AWS) ?

Answer (score 1):

While some third parties such as ACloudGuru provide sandbox accounts with an additional fee, and there are also third party projects such as LocalStack that provide an AWS compatible to selected services, AWS does not provide any free sandbox API endpoints for testing other than free tier.